# Java painting program: How to leave a trail behind a shape

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I am trying to create a painting program, which allows you to move a shape and it paints the shape onto a `JFrame`.  However, when I paint, it does not leave a trail.  I figured that it does not leave a trail because I am overriding the paint method and that clears my previous painted object when I want to paint a new one.  But when I remove the code that overrides this and run the program the shape leaves a trail behind but the buttons on the top of the frame get all messed up.

MovingBlockFrame.java:

```
package MovingBlock;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class MovingBlockFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener, ChangeListener{


   FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 10, 10);
   JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
   JButton circle = new JButton("Circle");
   JButton rectangle = new JButton("Rectangle");
   JButton color = new JButton("Color");
   JSlider speed = new JSlider(0, 100, 10);

   Graphics2D test3;
   int desiredWidth = 780;
   int desiredHeight = 800;
   MovingBlockCanvas background = new MovingBlockCanvas();
   int paintSpeed = 10;
   boolean diagonalKeysDown;
    boolean diagonalKeysUp;

    public MovingBlockFrame(){


    
    setTitle("Painter");
    buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    setSize(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    
    KeyListener();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(flo);
    buttonPanel.add(circle);
    buttonPanel.add(rectangle);
    buttonPanel.add(color);
    buttonPanel.add(speed);

    

    background.desiredShape = "Circle";
    background.addKeyListener(this);

    add(background);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    setVisible(true);
    
    
    
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    MovingBlockFrame frame = new MovingBlockFrame();
    
    frame.addKeyListener(frame);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent input) {

    int pressed = input.getKeyCode();
    if(pressed == 83){
        diagonalKeysDown = true;
        background.xValue+= paintSpeed;
        background.repaint();
    }else if(pressed == 68 && !diagonalKeysDown){
        background.yValue+=paintSpeed;
        background.repaint();
    }else if(pressed == 87 ){
        diagonalKeysUp = true;
        background.xValue-=paintSpeed;
        background.repaint();
    }else if(pressed == 65 ){
        background.yValue-=paintSpeed;
        background.repaint();
    } if(diagonalKeysDown && pressed == 68){
        background.yValue+=paintSpeed;
        background.xValue+= paintSpeed;
        background.repaint();
    } if(diagonalKeysUp  && pressed == 68){
        background.yValue+=paintSpeed;
        background.xValue-= paintSpeed;
        background.repaint();
    } if(diagonalKeysDown && pressed == 65){
        background.yValue-=paintSpeed;
        background.xValue+= paintSpeed;
        background.repaint();
    } if(diagonalKeysUp && pressed == 65){
        background.yValue-=paintSpeed;
        background.xValue-= paintSpeed;
        background.repaint();
    }
}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent input) {
    int released = input.getKeyCode();
    if(released == 83){
        diagonalKeysDown = false;
    } if(released == 87){
        diagonalKeysUp = false;
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent input) {

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if(command.equals("Circle")){
            background.desiredShape = "Circle";
            background.repaint();
        }else if (command.equals("Rectangle")){
            background.desiredShape = "Rectangle";
            background.repaint();
        }else if(command.equals("Color")){
            //ColorSliders test = new ColorSliders();
        }
    
}


public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
    JSlider source = (JSlider) event.getSource();
    if(source.getValueIsAdjusting() != true){
        paintSpeed = source.getValue();
    }
    
}

public void KeyListener(){
    buttonPanel.addKeyListener(this);
    circle.addKeyListener(this);
    rectangle.addKeyListener(this);
    circle.addActionListener(this);
    rectangle.addActionListener(this);
    color.addKeyListener(this);
    color.addActionListener(this);
    speed.addKeyListener(this);
    speed.addChangeListener(this);
}

}
```

MovingBlockCanvas.java:

```
package MovingBlock;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MovingBlockCanvas extends JPanel {

int xValue = 50;
int yValue = 50;
String desiredShape;


public MovingBlockCanvas(){

}


public void paint(Graphics render){
    
    //super.paint(render);
    
    render.setColor(ColorPanel.getColor2());
    
    if(desiredShape == "Rectangle"){
        render.fillRect(yValue, xValue, 50, 50);
    }
    if(desiredShape == "Circle"){
        render.fillOval(yValue, xValue, 50, 50);

    }   
}
}
```

The problem is in the paint method when I override the method I will not leave a trail for the shapes.  Also if you have any coding tips I would love to hear them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: At least two options come to mind, either paint to an offscreen `BufferedImage` and then paint this image to the screen, then it won't be cleared or store a series of points in some kind of `List` and play join the dots by painting lines between the points

Comment: Do you know anywhere I can read up on BuffereImages because at this moment I know very little of them.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966290/java-paint-not-drawing-in-swing/23966309#23966309) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909375/multiple-problems-regarding-java-paint-program-while-painting/16909442#16909442)

Comment: [Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/). `BufferedImage` allows you access to it's "contents" via a number of different ways, but the most useful in your case is via it's `Graphics` context, which would allow you to paint to the image just like you would the screen

Comment: Thank you I will read up on Buffered Images.

Comment: I'd also have a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: And `desiredShape == "Rectangle"` isn't how `String`s should be compared in Java

Comment: Thank you for the tips...For the string comparing should I use .equals() ?

Comment: Yes or `String#equalsIgnoreCase` depending on your needs

Comment: I do believe that the image should stay if you don't explicitly clear it. So I think your `render.setColor(ColorPanel...);` is re-coloring the painting surface to be the same as the panel. Try commenting that out.

Comment: @Lightning you should look at the comment above and try that.

Comment: Got it to paint perfectly using a Buffered Image and I got to learn more about buffered images which is useful...Thanks to everyone that posted

Comment: Then you should post your own solution and accept it for others to gain from what you've learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I learned to fix this error.  I just had to create a new buffered image then draw to that image, then redraw the buffered image using the paintComponent method.  This is the class I created with the updated code to make the program paint and leave a trail behind the shape while still overriding the paintComponenet method.

```
public class MovingBlockCanvas extends JPanel {

int xValue = 50;
int yValue = 50;
int width = 10;
int height = 10;
String desiredShape;
BufferedImage drawing;

public MovingBlockCanvas(){

}

public void drawShapes(){
    if(drawing == null){
        createBufferedImage();
    }
    if(desiredShape.equals("Rectangle")){
        Graphics2D g = drawing.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(ColorPanel.getColor2());
        g.fillRect(yValue, xValue, width, height);
        g.dispose();
    }
    if(desiredShape.equals("Circle")){
        Graphics2D g = drawing.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(ColorPanel.getColor2());
        g.fillOval(yValue, xValue, width, height);
        g.dispose();
    }
    repaint();
}

public void createBufferedImage() {


        BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.dispose();
        drawing = buffer;

}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics render){

    super.paintComponent(render);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) render.create();
    if(drawing == null){
        createBufferedImage();
    }
    g.drawImage(drawing, 0, 0, this);
    g.dispose();


}


}
```

Thank you to everyone that helped me learn this!